# Mixing standard and pre-emptible instances in autoscaling instance groups

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a group of CPU-bound worker machines that I want to scale, but I'm also cheap. Assuming that the work MUST always be done in a somewhat timely fashion regardless of instance cost, would it make sense to have something like:

- An instance group of pre-emptible instances with a target CPU of 80%
- An instance group of regular instances with a target CPU of 90%

In this case I would expect that:

1. When possible, the pre-emptible instance group will scale up to meet demand while the standard group shrinks to its configured minimum.
2. When pre-emptible instances cannot meet demand the standard instance group will grow.

Will the GCE instance group scaling work as I expect? Is there another scheduler that I should consider?

For reference, this would be the second iteration of worker infrastructure in GCP. Currently we're using 32x n1-standard-8 instances in a non-autoscaling group, but we're hoping to cut our core count in half.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find public documentation on the internals of the load balancer but [this whitepaper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/44824.pdf) might be of your interest.

I believe your approach to use two instances groups might work for your case. Since there is no way to predict which group will autoscale first, playing with the target CPU should actually give you a way to weight which group auto scales first.

I can also see one caveat which is defining the maximum number of nodes in your non preemptible group. What I mean is that  if this group reaches the maximum number of nodes, and the [preemptible group is not able to scale up](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible) your application might get impacted. In any case, if you are using this type of VMs, your application should be fault tolerant .